# upload string as image to trello api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, base64

I'm trying to upload an image file to trello api.
The code below does the job, but the file is uploaded as a text string.

C:/file holds a text string.
If I take that string and run it troug an online base64 converter like https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter I get a fine png image.

The API documentation specifies that I can set filename, mimetype as strings and file to attach as multipart/form-data Format: binary

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-attachments-post

How can I convert this image to an image before uploading it?

```
import requests
import base64

key = "xxx"
token = "yyy"

url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/618390bbdc3cb10550c9912b/attachments"

pathToFile ="C:/file"

f = open(pathToFile, "r")
file = f.read()
f.close()

message_bytes = file.encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
base64_message = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')

response = requests.post(url, params={'token':token,'key':key, 'mimeType ':'png', 'name':'fisk.png'}, files={'file':base64_message})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this post from  Adrian Sutton https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Mime-types-of-attachments-uploaded-to-Trello/qaq-p/1369920

I ended up with this code, that also handle the mimetype corect:

```
import requests
import base64

def attachFileToCardID(key,token, trelloCardID, theFile, theName, theMIMEtype):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(file)
    resp = requests.post("https://trello.com/1/cards/{}/attachments".format(trelloCardID),
                         params={'key': key, 'token': token},
                         files={'file': (theName, imgdata, theMIMEtype)})
    return resp.status_code

key = "xxx"
token = "yyy"

pathToFile ="C:/file.txt"

f = open(pathToFile, "r")
file = f.read()
f.close()

x = attachFileToCardID(key,token,'zzz', file, 'filename.png','image/png')
```